# Play [Scala]: How to flatten a JSON object

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following JSON...

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "id": "1234",
    "type": "file",
    "length": 395
  }
}
```

... how do I convert it to

```
{
  "metadata.id": "1234",
  "metadata.type": "file",
  "metadata.length": 395
}
```

Tx.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is definitely not trivial, but possible by trying to flatten it recursively. I haven't tested this thoroughly, but it works with your example and some other basic one's I've come up with using arrays:

```
object JsFlattener {

    def apply(js: JsValue): JsValue = flatten(js).foldLeft(JsObject(Nil))(_++_.as[JsObject])

    def flatten(js: JsValue, prefix: String = ""): Seq[JsValue] = {
        js.as[JsObject].fieldSet.toSeq.flatMap{ case (key, values) =>
            values match {
                case JsBoolean(x) => Seq(Json.obj(concat(prefix, key) -> x))
                case JsNumber(x) => Seq(Json.obj(concat(prefix, key) -> x))
                case JsString(x) => Seq(Json.obj(concat(prefix, key) -> x))
                case JsArray(seq) => seq.zipWithIndex.flatMap{ case (x, i) => flatten(x, concat(prefix, key + s"[$i]")) }  
                case x: JsObject => flatten(x, concat(prefix, key))
                case _ => Seq(Json.obj(concat(prefix, key) -> JsNull))
            }
        }
    }

    def concat(prefix: String, key: String): String = if(prefix.nonEmpty) s"$prefix.$key" else key

}
```

`JsObject` has the `fieldSet` method that returns a `Set[(String, JsValue)]`, which I mapped, matched against the `JsValue` subclass, and continued consuming recursively from there.

You can use this example by passing a `JsValue` to `apply`:

```
val json = Json.parse("""
    {
      "metadata": {
        "id": "1234",
        "type": "file",
        "length": 395
      }
    }
"""
JsFlattener(json)
```

*We'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to make the code more beautiful looking.*

Comment: I think "js.as[JsObject]" fails when this is not passed an object. "seq.zipWithIndex.flatMap{ case (x, i) => flatten(x..." will then only work if every element of the array is an object. Any instance of "x": ["a","b"] will throw an exception as flatten(x...) is passed a JsString, not a JsObject.

Comment: I am new to scala so how to call this function, and what import libraries we use for JsValue. If we pass the Dataframe then what changes we should make in this code?

Answer (score 10):

You can do this pretty concisely with Play's [JSON transformers](http://mandubian.com/2012/10/29/unveiling-play-2-dot-1-json-api-part3-json-transformers/). The following is off the top of my head, and I'm sure it could be greatly improved on:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val flattenMeta = (__ \ 'metadata).read[JsObject].flatMap(
  _.fields.foldLeft((__ \ 'metadata).json.prune) {
    case (acc, (k, v)) => acc andThen __.json.update(
      Reads.of[JsObject].map(_ + (s"metadata.$k" -> v))
    )
  }
)
```

And then:

```
val json = Json.parse("""
  {
    "metadata": {
      "id": "1234",
      "type": "file",
      "length": 395
    }
  }
""")
```

And:

```
scala> json.transform(flattenMeta).foreach(Json.prettyPrint _ andThen println)
{
  "metadata.id" : "1234",
  "metadata.type" : "file",
  "metadata.length" : 395
}
```

Just change the path if you want to handle `metadata` fields somewhere else in the tree.

---

Note that using a transformer may be overkill here—see e.g. Pascal Voitot's input in [this thread](https://twitter.com/travisbrown/status/479250678666108928), where he proposes the following:

```
(json \ "metadata").as[JsObject].fields.foldLeft(Json.obj()) {
  case (acc, (k, v)) => acc + (s"metadata.$k" -> v)
}
```

It's not as composable, and you'd probably not want to use `as` in real code, but it may be all you need.

Comment: Beautiful Json transformer :)

Comment: Thanks, @JulienLafont, but actually I don't particularly like it—I feel like the code still kind of obscures the intent. There's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: Still seems tight to me; wrapped in a function passing params - `def doDotNotation(jsPath: JsPath, prefix: String): JsObject`. Useful using a recursive to add dot notation to nested `JsObjects`

Answer (score 4):

Here's my take on this problem, based on @Travis Brown's 2nd solution.

It recursively traverses the json and prefixes each key with its parent's key.

```
def flatten(js: JsValue, prefix: String = ""): JsObject = js.as[JsObject].fields.foldLeft(Json.obj()) {
    case (acc, (k, v: JsObject)) => {
        if(prefix.isEmpty) acc.deepMerge(flatten(v, k))
        else acc.deepMerge(flatten(v, s"$prefix.$k"))
    }
    case (acc, (k, v)) => {
        if(prefix.isEmpty) acc + (k -> v)
        else acc + (s"$prefix.$k" -> v)
    }
}
```

which turns this:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "id": "1234",
    "type": "file",
    "length": 395
  },
  "foo": "bar",
  "person": {
    "first": "peter",
    "last": "smith",
    "address": {
      "city": "Ottawa",
      "country": "Canada"
    }
  }
}
```

into this:

```
{
  "metadata.id": "1234",
  "metadata.type": "file",
  "metadata.length": 395,
  "foo": "bar",
  "person.first": "peter",
  "person.last": "smith",
  "person.address.city": "Ottawa",
  "person.address.country": "Canada"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Trev has the best solution here, completely generic and recursive, but it's missing a case for array support. I'd like something that works in this scenario:

turn this:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "id": "1234",
    "type": "file",
    "length": 395
  },
  "foo": "bar",
  "person": {
    "first": "peter",
    "last": "smith",
    "address": {
      "city": "Ottawa",
      "country": "Canada"
    },
    "kids": ["Bob", "Sam"]
  }
}
```

into this:

```
{
  "metadata.id": "1234",
  "metadata.type": "file",
  "metadata.length": 395,
  "foo": "bar",
  "person.first": "peter",
  "person.last": "smith",
  "person.address.city": "Ottawa",
  "person.address.country": "Canada",
  "person.kids[0]": "Bob",
  "person.kids[1]": "Sam"
}
```

I've arrived at this, which appears to work, but seems overly verbose. Any help in making this pretty would be appreciated.

```
def flatten(js: JsValue, prefix: String = ""): JsObject = js.as[JsObject].fields.foldLeft(Json.obj()) {
  case (acc, (k, v: JsObject)) => {
    val nk = if(prefix.isEmpty) k else s"$prefix.$k"
    acc.deepMerge(flatten(v, nk))
  }
  case (acc, (k, v: JsArray)) => {
    val nk = if(prefix.isEmpty) k else s"$prefix.$k"
    val arr = flattenArray(v, nk).foldLeft(Json.obj())(_++_)
    acc.deepMerge(arr)
  }
  case (acc, (k, v)) => {
    val nk = if(prefix.isEmpty) k else s"$prefix.$k"
    acc + (nk -> v)
  }
}

def flattenArray(a: JsArray, k: String = ""): Seq[JsObject] = {
  flattenSeq(a.value.zipWithIndex.map {
    case (o: JsObject, i: Int) =>
      flatten(o, s"$k[$i]")
    case (o: JsArray, i: Int) =>
      flattenArray(o, s"$k[$i]")
    case a =>
      Json.obj(s"$k[${a._2}]" -> a._1)
  })
}

def flattenSeq(s: Seq[Any], b: Seq[JsObject] = Seq()): Seq[JsObject] = {
  s.foldLeft[Seq[JsObject]](b){
    case (acc, v: JsObject) =>
      acc:+v
    case (acc, v: Seq[Any]) =>
      flattenSeq(v, acc)
  }
}
```

Comment: how to call this method for a large number for json strings inside multiple files?

Comment: Hey I am also looking for a similar kind of solution but I want my JSONs to be splitted into N no.of jsons according to the N no.of elements.
Here is my question and still unanswered.:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51668341/flat-nested-json-to-header-level-using-scala

Answer (score 0):

Thanks m-z, it is very helpful. (I'm not so familiar with Scala.)

I'd like to add a line for "flatten" working with primitive JSON array like "{metadata: ["aaa", "bob"]}".

```
  def flatten(js: JsValue, prefix: String = ""): Seq[JsValue] = {

    // JSON primitive array can't convert to JsObject
    if(!js.isInstanceOf[JsObject]) return Seq(Json.obj(prefix -> js))

    js.as[JsObject].fieldSet.toSeq.flatMap{ case (key, values) =>
      values match {
        case JsBoolean(x) => Seq(Json.obj(concat(prefix, key) -> x))
        case JsNumber(x) => Seq(Json.obj(concat(prefix, key) -> x))
        case JsString(x) => Seq(Json.obj(concat(prefix, key) -> x))
        case JsArray(seq) => seq.zipWithIndex.flatMap{ case (x, i) => flatten(x, concat(prefix, key + s"[$i]")) }
        case x: JsObject => flatten(x, concat(prefix, key))
        case _ => Seq(Json.obj(concat(prefix, key) -> JsNull))
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous solutions, have tried to simplify the code a bit

```
  def getNewKey(oldKey: String, newKey: String): String = {
    if (oldKey.nonEmpty) oldKey + "." + newKey else newKey
  }

  def flatten(js: JsValue, prefix: String = ""): JsObject = {
    if (!js.isInstanceOf[JsObject]) return Json.obj(prefix -> js)
    js.as[JsObject].fields.foldLeft(Json.obj()) {
      case (o, (k, value)) => {
        o.deepMerge(value match {
          case x: JsArray => x.as[Seq[JsValue]].zipWithIndex.foldLeft(o) {
            case (o, (n, i: Int)) => o.deepMerge(
              flatten(n.as[JsValue], getNewKey(prefix, k) + s"[$i]")
            )
          }
          case x: JsObject => flatten(x, getNewKey(prefix, k))
          case x => Json.obj(getNewKey(prefix, k) -> x.as[JsValue])
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: how can i call the method. very new to scala and functional programming. I read the JSON files  then what should i do?