# how to denormalize JSON in spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, denormalization

say for example this is the JSON as below. i have actually took this from amazon website but i think this works for the question.

```
{
    "player": {
        "username": "user1",
        "characteristics": {
            "race": "Human",
            "class": "Warlock",
            "subclass": "Dawnblade",
            "power": 300,
            "playercountry": "USA"
        },
        "arsenal": {
            "kinetic": {
                "name": "Sweet Business",
                "type": "Auto Rifle",
                "power": 300,
                "element": "Kinetic"
            },
            "energy": {
                "name": "MIDA Mini-Tool",
                "type": "Submachine Gun",
                "power": 300,
                "element": "Solar"
            },
            "power": {
                "name": "Play of the Game",
                "type": "Grenade Launcher",
                "power": 300,
                "element": "Arc"
            }
        },
        "armor": {
            "head": "Eye of Another World",
            "arms": "Philomath Gloves",
            "chest": "Philomath Robes",
            "leg": "Philomath Boots",
            "classitem": "Philomath Bond"
        },
        "location": {
            "map": "Titan",
            "waypoint": "The Rig"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to convert this to below and save as avro. I am new to spark programming so wrapping my head around the functional style is a bit difficult coming java background. please atleast guide me so i can write code by myself.

```
{
    "player.username": "user1",
    "player.characteristics.race": "Human",
    "player.characteristics.class": "Warlock",
    "player.characteristics.subclass": "Dawnblade",
    "player.characteristics.power": 300,
    "player.characteristics.playercountry": "USA",
    "player.arsenal.kinetic.name": "Sweet Business",
    "player.arsenal.kinetic.type": "Auto Rifle",
    "player.arsenal.kinetic.power": 300,
    "player.arsenal.kinetic.element": "Kinetic",
    "player.arsenal.energy.name": "MIDA Mini-Tool",
    "player.arsenal.energy.type": "Submachine Gun",
    "player.arsenal.energy.power": 300,
    "player.arsenal.energy.element": "Solar",
    "player.arsenal.power.name": "Play of the Game",
    "player.arsenal.power.type": "Grenade Launcher",
    "player.arsenal.power.power": 300,
    "player.arsenal.power.element": "Arc",
    "player.armor.head": "Eye of Another World",
    "player.armor.arms": "Philomath Gloves",
    "player.armor.chest": "Philomath Robes",
    "player.armor.leg": "Philomath Boots",
    "player.armor.classitem": "Philomath Bond",
    "player.location.map": "Titan",
    "player.location.waypoint": "The Rig"
}
```

Comment: [Querying Spark SQL DataFrame with complex types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28332494/9613318)

Comment: Avro (and Parquet) can perfectly accept nested structure exactly as written

Answer (score 0):

It is actually not much spark related, you just need a function to  flatten the nested json string to a new json string. The code sample would be something if you have RDD[String] first.

```
rdd.mapPartitions(ps => ps.map(jsonFlatten))
```

and then convert the `rdd` to `dataframe`

a sample `jsonFlatten` can be found from here:

[Play [Scala]: How to flatten a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273433/play-scala-how-to-flatten-a-json-object)

Comment: how can use those flatten methods while reading Multiple JSON Strings inside multiple files ?

Comment: I get below error when trying to use the method you mentioned. not sure what i am doing wrong.                                                           
 Type mismatch, expected: Iterator[Row] => Iterator[NotInferedU], actual: Iterator[Row] => Any 
Type mismatch, expected: Row => NotInferedB, actual: (JsValue, String) => JsObject
Type mismatch, expected: Row => NotInferedB, actual: (JsValue, String) => JsObject