# Flat nested JSON to header level using scala

Tags: json, apache-spark, json4s

Below is my sample JSON and can be nested to any level deep:

```
{
    "key1": {
        "keyA": 'valueI'
    },
    "key2": {
        "keyB": 'valueII'
    },
    "key3": [
    {
    "a":1,
    "b":2
    },
    {
    "a":1,
    "b":2
    }
    ]
}
```

This shloud be splitted up into 2 JSONs as Key3 has 2 array elements. Output should be like this:

```
JSON1 =
{
"key1_keyA":'valueI',
"key2_keyB":'valueII',
"key3_a":1,
"key3_b":2
}
JSON2=
{
"key1_keyA":'valueI',
"key2_keyB":'valueII',
"key3_a":1,
"key3_b":2
}
```

I am getting this kind of JSON from source and reading it from SPARK framework using scala.

Comment: What approaches have you tried ?

Comment: I am looking for an approach which will not hinder my performance as the Array element may contain upto thousands of values i.e 1 JSON can generate thousands of records and there can be thousands of JSONs like this.